# Is it Right Usage method of Base & Derived Class Relationship?

Tags: c++, mfc

Used Compiler : VS2010

Base Class : Parent Class

Derived Class : Child0 Class

Instance & Call : MainFrame(Child0 Class)

```
class parent /*parent Class*/
{
public: /*Base Func*/
virtual void OnAutoEntry();
virtual void OnInitParam(){};
virtual void OnInitSequence(){};
virtual void OnRunSequence(){};

private:/*Private Call Func*/
void OnSeqInitPartFunc();
void OnSeqStartDoneFunc();
}

void parent::OnAutoEntry() //doesn't understand function action
{
    // How did the parent class know the child function and called it?
    OnInitParam();
    OnSeqInitPartFunc();
    OnSeqStartDoneFunc();
}

class child0 : public parent
{
    void OnAutoEntry();    //propose : overridding
    void OnInitParam();    //propose : overridding
    void OnInitSequence();    //propose : overridding
    void OnRunSequence();    //propose : overridding
}
```

create overriding function on child0 class.

```
void child0::OnInitParam()
{AfxMessageBox(_T("Child :: OnInitParam() Called By Parent"));}
```

OnInitSequence, OnRunSequence are Samethings.

I Call this Function on MainFrame

```
void child0::OnAutoEntry()
{parent::OnAutoEntry(); //call parent function}
```

My Expected Result : Inactive. No Printed Message.

But Result is that message is printed.

Comment: How do you create and use object of `child0`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: "How did the parent class know the child function and called it?" -- that's what virtual functions are all about: the function to be called is selected only *at runtime*.

Comment: um.. but Is not it illegal for a base class to call a derived class function?

Comment: child0 overrides the virtual function OnInitParam.  If you don't want the parent class to call the overridden function, you can remove virtual.  virtual allows the parent class to call overridden functions without knowing implementation details.